# Getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable while iterating multi level JSON object

Tags: python, json

I have following JSON get response:

```
{
"id": "mov_BO381oEATXonG6bj",
"object": "movement",
"amount": 59400,
"post_date": "2020-04-17T00:00:00.000Z",
"description": "Traspaso de:Fintoc SpA",
"transaction_date": "2020-04-16T11:31:12.000Z",
"currency": "CLP",
"reference_id": "123740123",
"type": "transfer",
"pending": false,
"recipient_account": null,
"sender_account": {
    "holder_id": "771806538",
    "holder_name": "Comercial y Producción SpA",
    "number": "1530108000",
    "institution": {
      "id": "cl_banco_de_chile",
      "name": "Banco de Chile",
      "country": "cl"
    }
},
"comment": "Pago factura 198"

},
 {
    "id": "mov_4Ag8xaHXzvq3ea2b",
    "description": "0257478262 Transf.",
    "amount": 450000,
    "currency": "CLP",
    "post_date": "2022-12-01T00:00:00Z",
    "transaction_date": null,
    "type": "transfer",
    "recipient_account": null,
    "sender_account": {
        "holder_id": "257478262",
        "number": null,
        "institution": null,
        "holder_name": "Maria Marco"
    },
    "comment": null,
    "reference_id": "003922335",
    "pending": false,
    "object": "movement"
}
```

I have the following python script to iterate through the object and clasify the transactions, but I am getting the following error while iterating to the inner transaction item. The outer transaction item does not give error, but when I want to iterate through the inner item, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/berra/Python/movements.py", line 59, in <module>
for inner_transaction in outer_transaction['sender_account']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The code is the following:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.fintoc.com/v1/accounts/acc_qNDRKQeTpbAKvpnW/movements?link_token=token"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "authorizedKey."
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Parse the JSON data
transactions = json.loads(response.text)

expenses = []
incomes = []

#print(response.text)
for outer_transaction in transactions:
    # if movimiento['sender_account'] is None:
    #     expenses.append(movimiento)

    if outer_transaction['description'] == 'Traspaso de:Fintoc SpA':
        incomes.append(outer_transaction)
   
    if 'sender_account' in outer_transaction:
        #for inner_transaction in outer_transaction:
        for inner_transaction in outer_transaction['sender_account']:
            if inner_transaction['holder_name']=='Maria Marco':
               incomes.append(outer_transaction)
    
print("Expenses:", expenses)
print("Incomes:", incomes)
```

The API documentation I am using is available here: https://docs.fintoc.com/reference/movements-list

I have tried a lot of options to try to solve this but I was not able to make it. Does anyone has any clue about what I am missing or doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Modify your condition to also check if there is a value under 'sender_account' key `if 'sender_account' in outer_transaction and outer_transaction['sender_account']:`

Comment: You mean like this:
`if 'sender_account' in outer_transaction and outer_transaction['sender_account']:`

If so, I get the following now:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/berra/Python/movements.py", line 30, in <module>
    if inner_transaction['holder_name']=='Buildbim Spa':
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: That error means that `inner_transaction` is a string and not a dictionary. You can try using a try-except block to see what value is stored there, implement it like this: `try: inner_transaction['holder_name'] == 'Buildbim Spa': ... except: print(f"inner_transaction Error: {inner_transaction}") continue`

Comment: I got this now:
`inner_transaction Error: holder_id
inner_transaction Error: number
inner_transaction Error: institution
inner_transaction Error: holder_name
inner_transaction Error: holder_id
inner_transaction Error: number
inner_transaction Error: institution
inner_transaction Error: holder_name
`

Comment: That means that your `inner_transaction` is not a dictionary but you are already **inside** the `inner_transaction` and you are iterating over the *keys* of `inner_transaction` which are *strings*. Try printing some variables to see what is inside of them (e.g. what is inside of `outer_transaction`)

Comment: When I print outer_transaction,  I got this:

`{'amount': 450000,
 'comment': None,
 'currency': 'CLP',
 'description': '0257478262 Transf.',
 'id': 'mov_4Ag8xaHXzvq3ea2b',
 'object': 'movement',
 'pending': False,
 'post_date': '2022-12-01T00:00:00Z',
 'recipient_account': None,
 'reference_id': '003922335',
 'sender_account': {'holder_id': '257478262',
                    'holder_name': 'Maria Agustina De Marco',
                    'institution': None,
                    'number': None},`

Comment: There is no "inner_transaction", per se, inside the `outer_transaction['sender_account']`. If you want to access *holder_id* from *sender_account* you just use `outer_transaction['sender_account']['holder_id']`

Comment: Got my answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure how can I mark your comment as the answer for this question? Maybe you can add a comment as the answer to this and I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inner_transaction` () is not an iterable, to access a value inside `inner_transaction` you just need to use a *key*, e.g. `outer_transaction['sender_account']['holder_id']`